# Can't understand the meaning of a formula describing a stable equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium

I've found this formula in a book and I can't understand its meaning:

$$\frac{df}{dx}\biggr|_{x_0} < 0$$

It describes the condition of an object to being in a $\textit{stable}$ equilibrium.

At first glance, it looks like an equivalent form for $f'(x_0) $  but it doesn't make sense as the first derivative, in this case, must be equal to (and not smaller than) zero.

Comment: Which book? Also, $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\rvert_{x = x_0}$ is indeed a common way of writing $f'(x_0)$, so it is quite probable this is a typo.

Comment: Mmm... puzzling...

It's Fitzpatrick's "Introduction to Celestial Mechanics"


The formula should be referring to what happens at the "left" of $x_o$  (when $x < x_0$)

Comment: Is $f$ perhaps force? If so then $f$ is the first derivative of the potential and hence your condition is for the second derivative of potential

Comment: @Klest that must be a kind of [Mechanical equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium)

Comment: $~~$Which page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just a test of what kind of potential minimum you are sitting in (interpreting $f$ as a force)?

So if $d f/d x < 0$, and $f = -d U/d x$, where $U$ is the potential, then your condition reduces to $d^2 U/dx^2 > 0$ at $x=x_0$.

If $f$ only depends on $x$ then that clearly marks a local potential minimum (assuming that $f(x_0)=0$).

Beware though, this argument applies to a case where the potential only depends on $x$. If the potential actually depends on more than one independent variable then (e.g.) a saddle point in the potential is still possible, which would not be a stable equilibrium point.